# C# i have to type the same thing 3 times for it too work, how do i fix this?

Tags: c#

this is just a simple program i made so that requires a password for opening chrome.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;


namespace Bitch
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type Help If You Need More Info:");


        if(Console.ReadLine() == "UneedPassMate")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe");
            System.Environment.Exit(0);

        }
        if(Console.ReadLine() == "Help")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("To Open Chrome\n You Will Need To Enter A Password>");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "help")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("To Open Chrome\n You Will Need To Enter A Password>");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        }


}
}
```

but evertime i type "help" or "Help"nothing happens until i i've typed either one of em 3 times. Does anyone how to fix this? not the first time this has happend either.

Comment: try adding var text = Console.ReadLine(); before your if conditions and check if(text == "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to read the user's input one time. Try this instead:

```
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    if(input == "UneedPassMate")
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe");
        System.Environment.Exit(0);

    }
    if (input.ToLower() == "help")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("To Open Chrome\n You Will Need To Enter A Password>");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you execute `Console.ReadLine()`, your program will wait for input.

You should execute it once, assign the result to a variable, then check the variable.

```
Console.WriteLine("Type Help If You Need More Info:");

string input = Console.ReadLine();

if(input == "UneedPassMate")
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe");
    System.Environment.Exit(0);
}
if (input == "Help" || input == "help")
{
    Console.WriteLine("To Open Chrome\n You Will Need To Enter A Password>");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to pure functional programming languages, functions need not be pure and may very well return different output each time they have been called. `Console.ReadLine()` is an example of an "impure" function as for each of your 3 calls, it reads a string from console input and returns whatever the user was entering.

If you only want the user to input once, you need to store the result of the call to `Console.ReadLine()` and then use that result for your subsequent tests.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;


namespace Bitch
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type Help If You Need More Info:");

    string input = Console.ReadLine(); // Only ask for input once not 3 times!

    if(input == "UneedPassMate")
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe");
        System.Environment.Exit(0);

    }
    if(input == "Help")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("To Open Chrome\n You Will Need To Enter A Password>");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    if (input == "help")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("To Open Chrome\n You Will Need To Enter A Password>");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}


}
}
```